# Getiing "Error Opening Script File C:\Documents" in DOS command

Tags: windows, vba

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim a
ipaddress = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value
UserName = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value
Password = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value
Path = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 2).Value
a = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 2).Value 'Reports needs to be downloaded
aSplit = Split(a, ",")
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objOutStream, objjFSO, objShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\FTPCommand.txt",      ForWriting, True)
With objOutStream
.WriteLine UserName
.WriteLine Password
.WriteLine "binary"
.WriteLine Path
For i = 0 To UBound(aSplit)
    aSplit(i) = Trim(aSplit(i))
    .WriteLine "get ES." & aSplit(i)
Next
.WriteLine "quit"
.Close
End With
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k FTP -n -i -s:" & "C:\Documents and Settings\FTPCommand.txt" & " " & ipaddress, 1, True
End Sub
```

**Text File after running the macro code:**

```
Username
Password
binary
Path
get ES.1312
get ES.3243
get ES.4534
quit
```

The Commands in the Text file is not executed. I don't know how to fix it.

Please help...Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The path has spaces so must be quoted to distinguish it from other parts of the command line:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k FTP -n -i -s:" & """C:\Documents and Settings\FTPCommand.txt""" & " " & ipaddress, 1, True
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. It helped me a out. Facing another one problem. While executing, the FTP server is connected with the specified IP address. But after that the FTP is not asking username and password. But from the text file username, password, binary and location of the file is entered one by one. After that getting error "Please login with USER and PASS" in the line "get ES.XXXX".

Comment: I got the solution. Used USER "username" "password" command in the text file.